# How client unicasts a RENEW DHCP REQUEST if server id MUST not be filled in?

Tags: networking, network-programming, dhcp

When client is trying to renew it lease time, how does it unicasts to the server if the server id MUST NOT BE FILLED according to [RFC2131 4.3.2](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/2131/24.htm)

" DHCPREQUEST generated during RENEWING state:
'server identifier' MUST NOT be filled in, 'requested IP address' option MUST NOT be filled in, 'ciaddr' MUST be filled in with client's IP address. In this situation, the client is completely configured, and is trying to extend its lease. This message will be unicast, so no relay agents will be involved in its transmission. Because 'giaddr' is therefore not filled in, the DHCP server will trust the value in 'ciaddr', and use it when replying to the client.

A client MAY choose to renew or extend its lease prior to T1. The server may choose not to extend the lease (as a policy decision by the network administrator), but should return a DHCPACK message regardless."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`siaddr`, the "server identifier" field, is inside the DHCP message, which is send out using UDP, which has its own field for destination IP address in the IP header, so the client unicasts the renew packet to the known IP of the server.

Comment: isn't the server id is the same as server ip ? if not then what is server id ?

Comment: As far as I remember, `siaddr` is sent by the server in the offer message, and it's up to the client to accept or ignore. What I'm saying is that server IP is populated in the IP header of the UDP message, not the DHCP message, which is the payload here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I still don't understand the differences.

Comment: It's the same value (same IP address), just in different places. On DHCP renew there's no need for broadcasts since IP addresses are already known, so the client sends normal UDP message to the server with regular `sendto(2)`. There's *no need* to populate `siaddr` in the DHCP message body, it doesn't have any function here.

Answer (score 1):

Clients can send Renew DHCP Request messages via unicast even though "Server Identifier" must not be set, because "Server Identifier" is not neccesseary for sending the packets. 
When sending packets with unicast you only need to specify destination IP address, in this case the IP address of the DHCP server and this information client knows from the initialization stage.

"Server Identifier" is actually an option 54, "DHCP Option 54 - DHCP Server Identifier" used for selecting DHCP server in case when multiple DHCP servers respond with DHCP OFFER message to DHCP DISCOPVER message in the initialization phase. That's why it is a must to specify it in the SELECTING phase, but it is not neccesseary, or actually must not be set in the RENEWING and the REBINDING phase because the client allready knows which DHCP server it has selected.

"Server Identifier" is not "siaddr" filed of the DHCP Message. "Siaddr" is not one of the options, but a standard filed in the DHCP message filled only by DHCP Server.
"Server Identifier" and "siaddr" both have the values of an IP address of the DHCP server and I belive that that fact associate you to think they are used to send the DHCP message. They are however not used during sending and forwarding of teh packets, only destination IP address inside of the IP header is used for that.

Both "Server Identifier" and "siaddr" are actually used to find out the IP address of the DHCP server which is then used to send the DHCP Request messages directly to DHCP server via unicast.